# Is there a best practice to documenting a Command Line Interface?

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I have designed a few programs that have a CLI and want to document them as standard as possible. Are there any agreements out there as to the best way to do this?

An example:

Let's say the Program is "sayHello" and it takes in a few parameters: name and message. So a standard call would look like this:

```
> sayHello "Bob" "You look great"
```

Okay, so my command usage would look something like this:

```
sayHello [name] [message]
```

That may already be a mistake if brackets have a specific meaning in usage commands. But let's go a step farther and say "message" is optional:

```
sayHello [name] [message (optional)]
```

And then just one more wrinkle, what if there is a default we want to denote:

```
sayHello [name] [message (optional: default 'you look good')]
```

I realize this usage statement looks a little obtuse at this point. I'm really asking if there are somewhat agreed-upon standards on how to write these. I have a sneaking suspicion that the parenthesis and brackets all have specific meanings.

Comment: Follow conventions laid out in the most applicable `man` or (PowerShell `help`) or other reference documentation .. or just write it how you prefer. However, `[squareBracketsNormallyMeanOptional]` and the default is often discussed when talking about the option itself.

Comment: As above, but I've generally seen `progname arg1 arg2 [opt_arg3 (default:someval), opt_arg4, ...]`

Comment: I do understand the "hold" put on this question and it's fair. I wish there was an agreed upon way to open discussions like this as they may lead to (in this example) a more generalized standard where there is not one already defined. Also, the answers provided do, in fact, provide specific examples and resources to address the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I am unaware of any official standard, there are some efforts to provide conventions-by-framework. [Docopt](http://docopt.org/) is one such framework, and may suit your needs here. In their own words:

docopt helps you:

- define interface for your command-line app, and
- automatically generate parser for it.

There are implementations for [many programming languages](https://github.com/docopt), including [shell](https://github.com/docopt/docopts).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the manuals for common Unix commands (e.g. `man grep`) or the help documentation for Windows commands (e.g. `find /?`) and using them as a general guide.  If you picked either of those patterns (or used some elements common to both), you'd at least surprise the fewest number of people.

Apache commons also has [some](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html) [classes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html) in the [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) package that will print usage information for your particular set of command-line options.

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("file")
                      .withDescription("The file to be processed")
                      .hasArg()
                      .withArgName("FILE")
                      .isRequired()
                      .create('f'));
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("version")
                      .withDescription("Print the version of the application")
                      .create('v'));
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt("help").create('h'));

String header = "Do something useful with an input file\n\n";
String footer = "\nPlease report issues at http://example.com/issues";

HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
formatter.printHelp("myapp", header, options, footer, true);
```

Using the above will generate help output that looks like:

```
usage: myapp -f  [-h] [-v]
Do something useful with an input file

 -f,--file <FILE>   The file to be processed
 -h,--help
 -v,--version       Print the version of the application

Please report issues at http://example.com/issues
```